# why F# debugger lies?

Tags: visual-studio, error-handling, f#

Can anyone explain me why debugger of VS2012 is showing different values for same member of object? (See the figure)

http://s2.uploads.ru/jlkw0.png (Sorry for nonEnglish interface of VS, but I think the situation is clear.)

Here the code:

http://pastie.org/7186239

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The debugging experience seems to do a poor job of identifying the correct binding for identifiers.  In your example, this means that any identifier called `Source` is really showing the value of `this.Source`, rather than the corresponding property of the correct object.  Note that you can get the right value by hovering over `y` and expanding the members (although this is obviously not a great experience).

There are even more confusing ways that this issue manifests itself:

```
type T() =
    member val P = 1

    member this.DoSomething() =
        let P = "test"      // set breakpoint here, hover over P
        printfn "%i" this.P // set breakpoint here, hover over P

T().DoSomething()
```

Now, whichever instance of `P` you hover over, you get the wrong thing!

Comment: So, is it means that Studio is a little bit buggy? Or it is just a trick which I should remember?

Comment: I'd certainly call it a bug, yes.